# How to compare two images with different fromat?

Tags: image, matlab

I have two images with different format were taken by the same camera, same position, but with two different lenses. One image is a thermal image (IR) which contains 640X480 pixels. Each pixel contains a temperature signature for that particular pixel. The other image is a digital image with 2592X1944 pixels. Therefore, they are not identical. The digital image contains some information about the position of some targets. I'd like to see if the IR image is able to detect these targets through comparing each pixel from IR image with the corresponding one from the digital image. I am totally new to this field and any comment would be helpful and appreciated. How can I make these two image identical either in MATLAB (R2013a)or any other software?

Comment: use an image manipulation software to enlarge the small image to the size of the big one. i am thinking of gimp or imagemagic, but most image viewers with basic editing capabilities should work too.

Comment: Depending on your toolboxes, have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html

Comment: If you want a perfect alignment, and willing to consider video sequences instead of just images, you might find [this work](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/VideoAnalysis/Demos/Seq2Seq/Seq2Seq.html) of Irani and Caspi interesting. They also have an example of aligning IR and regular video sequence.

Comment: If you want to do it very accurately you would need to provide the focal lengths of the two lenses and the sizes of the sensors on the (presumably) two cameras, but if you just want to eyeball it, use `ImageMagick` to resize the smaller up to the size of the larger, or some multiple of it like this `convert smaller.jpg -resize 2592x1944 enlarged.jpg`. You may find Anthony Thyssen's flicker-compare script handy for flicking back and forth between the two images... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/flicker_cmp

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to go that deep in image processing  since the application of my proposal is for civil engineering field and also gaining a knowledge regarding to the field of image processing is not that easy. I've looked at what you've recommended in your comments, but found them very hard to be understood by a civil engineering guy. Is there exists any simplified method or procedure can I follow to produce two identically (or almost identically) pictures even before taking these pictures or after? and will this still be considered as an image processing? Thanks

Comment: By the way, is pixbuilder studio software have the same capabilities as gimp and imagemagick software in this regard? I am currently using pixbuilder studio for this purpose (by surrounding the targets with lines and then cutting the inside area. then in matlab, converting the entire picture to a binary coded picture (0 and 1) for further processing steps

Answer (score 0):

At research level, this is called **image registration**. It is the process of transforming different data (in your case images IR and Intensities images) to one coordinate system.

There is a lot of algorithms that performs such transformation based on features extracted from both images.

As start, I advise you to read this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) and since this article is related to matlab there is a technical article about [automating image registration using matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/automating-image-registration-with-matlab.html?refresh=true).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I need. So sorry for being late in my response because I just saw the suggestions.